# Typeahead.js only matches beginning of the word

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

My Typeahead code is:

```
var events = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 100,
        prefetch: {
            url: Ajax.pluginurl + 'json/events.json',
            ttl: 1
        }
    });

    events.initialize();

    initialize_events_typeahead ();

    function initialize_events_typeahead () {
        $('.event_name').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'event',
            displayKey: 'name',
            source: events.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="empty-message">',
                    Ajax.no_results_found,
                    '</div>'
                ].join('\n'),
                suggestion: function(data){
                    return '<p><strong>' + data.name + '</strong> - ' + data.description + '</p>';
                }
            },
            engine: Hogan
        });


        $('.event_name').on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function(e,datum) {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.event_description').val(datum.description);
        });
    }
```

For some reason, this code matches only the beggining of the name. However, on the demo http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/, prefetch section, with the same code as far as I see, it matches even when starting to type something in the middle of the world.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

EDIT: the JSON is:

```
[{"name":"P\u0159\u00edjezd host\u016f","description":"Cras ullamcorper ornare semper. Phasellus faucibus augue congue dapibus mollis. "},{"name":"Ob\u0159ad","description":"Curabitur fermentum diam quis viverra sodales. Phasellus sed sollicitudin magna, a dictum metus."},{"name":"Ve\u010dern\u00ed z\u00e1bava","description":"Curabitur fermentum diam quis viverra sodales."},{"name":"After-party","description":"Proin ipsum odio, vehicula vel diam a, dapibus suscipit velit. "},{"name":"Sn\u00eddan\u011b","description":"Proin ornare tempus ipsum at blandit. Nam hendrerit dolor et interdum vulputate."}]
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: I believe it's not working because the names in the JSON contain accents. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460272/typeahead-insensitive-accent

Comment: Hmm, I tried to remove the special characters, it didn't help..

Comment: I have the same problem, apparently it's an [issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/96) but the examples really show the matching results in the middle of the suggestions.

Comment: Yes! How do they do that than, when there's an issue for this?

Comment: A user isn't going to start typing in the middle of a word so you likely want to stick with only matching the beginning.

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059933/twitter-typeahead-js-how-to-return-all-matched-elements-within-a-string

Answer (score 11):

Not sure about why their samples show the middle words matching, but I [guess](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/96) you are supposed to develop your own matching algorithm ([datumTokenizer](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options)).

Here is my solution (temporary in case they implement something by default in the Bloodhound engine):

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({

    datumTokenizer: function(d){
        var tokens = [];
        //the available string is 'name' in your datum
        var stringSize = d.name.length;
        //multiple combinations for every available size
        //(eg. dog = d, o, g, do, og, dog)
        for (var size = 1; size <= stringSize; size++){          
          for (var i = 0; i+size<= stringSize; i++){
              tokens.push(d.name.substr(i, size));
          }
        }

        return tokens;
    },...
```

Comment: That post saved my life! I'm so frustrated using bloodhound, it's becoming a nightmare! Something as simple as this shouldn't take hours of research or code tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance all the foreign characters you are likely to encounter then you could normalize the input using the suggestion shown here:

[Typeahead insensitive accent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460272/typeahead-insensitive-accent)

However, if you don't know what characters are going to be inputted then instead you could use this JavaScript Unicode 6.3 Normalization library:

https://github.com/walling/unorm

Which you can install using the client-side package manager [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower).